# Running expensive task without blocking UI in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 2 app, created with Angular CLI, that has the following sequence of events:

1. An asynchronous event happens (e.g. the user clicks a button).

   1.1 An animation is triggered.

   1.2 An expensive process runs. It takes a few seconds.
2. The UI is updated with the result of the expensive process.

The problem I am having is that the animation and the UI freeze while the expensive process is running.

I made this simplified version that shows the issue:

http://plnkr.co/edit/13ieoXgMtaJfCq7Mijv7?p=preview

I tried using NgZone's `runOutsideAngular` to run the expensive process but it's the same as running it inline. I also tried using the Zone.js library but I am not familiar with it and I am getting error `'zone.js.d.ts' is not a module`

How can I "fork" this expensive process into a parallel thread/zone and then merge it into the main zone when it's done to gracefully update the UI? Or whatever solution is appropriate... It doesn't have to use zones explicitly.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: There is only one thread for javascript code in a browser. Can't you execute the code on a server?

Comment: run the expensive task in a web worker

Comment: @mh-dev: Thank you for the good info. I could consider running it on a server. The app I'm working on is a two-player game and one of the players can be the computer. Not ideal, but I don't care if the UI freezes for 2-3 seconds while the machine comes up with its move, as long as the animation runs smoothly and displays the person's move. Maybe if there is a way to know when the animation completed?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: Thank you. Any suggestions on how to get started with web workers in Angular 2? I did see that Angular 2 has a `WebWorkerInstance` class and I have seen packages like [this](https://github.com/haochi/angular2-web-worker). But it's not clear to me how to use them.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/2e1f3f003d436d26bf9e237d6d8e9336c3a935b8/modules/playground/src/web_workers I only tried it with Dart so far. I guess you need to build Angular from source to get fully generated examples. It's rather straight-forward once you know how it works.

Comment: Keep in mind that WebWorker is not supported by all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I know they already recommended Web Workers, but I didn't see any answer/comment mentioning Angular Web Workers in specific. Only drawback of Web Workers is that you cannot use inside a `worker` methods/functions that are declared outside the `worker`. So, if for example you are using a library's method in your heavy expensive process, then you can't use this.

If this is not the case, then you are good to go:

- Official Docs (pretty basic and short): https://angular.io/guide/web-worker
- Really useful tutorial (more extended): https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-execute-a-function-with-a-web-worker-on-a-different-thread-in-angular/

UPDATE: Code included in case links are invalidated. This is a simple example.

1. Create a file called `foo.worker.ts`

```js
addEventListener('message', ({ data }) => {
  // Do some stuff
  const response = 'This is the job result';

  // This internal method 'postMessage' is used to return the result
  postMessage(response);
});
```

2. Use the worker from another file:

```js
const worker = new Worker('./foo.worker', { type: 'module' });
  worker.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
    // This will get executed when the worker is finished and 
    //  calls 'postMessage'.
    // 'data' object is the result that is returned from the worker.
  };

  // This is what you call to initiate the worker process.
  // As a parameter you will send the info that the worker needs
  //   to do its job (In this case, 'hello').
  worker.postMessage('hello');
} else {
  // Web workers are not supported in this environment.
  // You should add a fallback so that your program still executes correctly.
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28061137)

Comment: @MhdAlaaAlhaj you are completely right. I just added the code with some comments for explanation. Thanks for the comment.